# (CSS) File is not listed within the file list of project Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern

Tags: typescript

I'm importing a CSS module file into a TS file, and am getting the above error. I have no problems importing any other types of files.

I've added the `"./typings.d.ts", "**/*.css"` to see if that was the issue. It errors with or without these includes. The `./typings.d.ts` file has this:

```
declare module '*.module.css' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

Full error is:

```
File '/Users/andy/my-repo/apps/docs/src/left-nav/nav-section.module.css' is not listed within the file list of project '/Users/andy/my-repo/tsconfig.src.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.ts(6307)
```

Here are my tsconfigs:

tsconfig.src.json (where the error is pointing to)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }],
    "types": ["vite/client", "bun-types", "web"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/**/*", "tmp", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.btest.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "./typings.d.ts", "**/*.css"]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "es2016"
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.test.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.src.json"
    }
  ]
}
```